# Is there a clean Pythonic way to override default method args in a subclass in Python?

Tags: python, oop, overriding, default

I am inheriting from a 3rd party class and want to change the default value on one of the class's methods. I can think of a few ways of doing this, but none feel clean.

So, if the base class is

```py
class Base:
    def foo(self, a=1, b=2, c=3):
        return a, b, c
```

I want a class `MyClass(Base)` where `b` defaults to `7` instead. So,

```py
my_obj = MyClass()
my_obj.foo()  # (1, 7, 3)
my_obj.foo(b=5)  # (1, 5, 3)
my_obj.foo(2, 4)  # (2, 4, 3)
my_obj.foo(8)  # (8, 7, 3)
```

I've been able to achieve the desired behavior by manually modifying args and kwargs, but it doesn't feel clean:

```py
class OptionOne(Base):
   
    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # b is the second argument, so it is an arg if and only if there are 2 or more args
        if len(args) < 2:
            # If b wasn't passed as an arg, update kwargs to default b to 7.
            kwargs['b'] = kwargs.get('b', 7)
        return super().foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

Try/excepting a type error seems a little neater, but it isn't that readable:

```py
class OptionTwo(Base):
    
    def foo(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return super().foo(b=7, *args, **kwargs)
        except TypeError:
            # If b was already specified (as an arg or kwarg) 
            #   "TypeError: foo() got multiple values for keyword argument 'b'"
            # will be raised, so we don't override b in this case.
            return super().foo(*args, **kwargs)
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this that I am missing?

Comment: Check out doing kwargs.setdefault

Comment: @SamDolan: `kwargs.setdefault` fails if `b` was passed positionally, though.

Comment: ah, I see. I guess you could do sort of locals() lookup if you really wanted to. I'd rethink the class design though because it's just awkward.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try something like the below. This is basically overwriting the default value of `b` in the constructor of the subclass.

```
class Base:
  def __init__(self, a=1, b=2, c=3):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
    self.c = c

  def print_me(self):
    print(self.a, self.b, self.c)


class MyClass(Base):
   def __init__(self, a=1, b=7, c=3):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(a, b, c)


test1 = Base()
test1.print_me()

test2 = MyClass()
test2.print_me()

test3 = MyClass(0, 1)
test3.print_me()

test4 = MyClass(b=5)
test4.print_me()
```

Output:

```
1 2 3
1 7 3
0 1 3
1 5 3
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I don't have access to the base class (it's from a 3rd party). And copying over all the other default params (besides b) also feels a little clunky, and wouldn't be robust to changes in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually change the defaults after defining a new method. It's not great, since defaults are stored only as a tuple without any explicit reference to the parameters they apply to.

```
class OptionTwo(Base):

    def foo(self, a, b, c):
        return super().foo(a, b, c)

    foo.__defaults__ = (Base.foo.__defaults__[:1]
                        + (7,)
                        + Base.foo.__defaults__[2:])
```

On the plus side, this is equivalent to setting the default values in the definition of `foo` itself, but doesn't require you to actually know the old defaults.

You could also abstract this to a decorator if you like.

```
def update_defaults(src, i, v):
    def _decorator(f):
        f.__defaults__ = src.__defaults__[:i] + (v,) + src.__defaults[i+1:]
        return f
    return _decorator


class OptionTwo(Base):
    @update_defaults(Base.__defaults__, 1, 7)
    def foo(self, a, b, c):
        return super().foo(a, b, c)
```